# EventLogger for MVC application

Tags: c#, beginner, object-oriented, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc

I have worked on one application related for booking space and required to store activity of user into table and access from admin side.
For that I have created one database entity and `EventLogger` class.

```
public partial class UserEventLog
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public Enum_SourceType SourceType { get; set; }
    public Enum_EventType EventType { get; set; }
    public string EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public Enum_LogType LogType { get; set; }
    public string LogMessage { get; set; }
    public string LogDescription { get; set; }
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
    public string HostName { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset EventTriggeredOn { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUser User { get; set; }
}
```

related enum

```
public enum Enum_SourceType
{
    User,
    Order
}
public enum Enum_LogType
{
    Information,
    Warning,
    Error
}
public enum Enum_EventType
{
    Create,
    Update,
    Delete,
    Duplicate,
    DownLoad,
    Preview,
    Search,
    AppliedCoupon,
    Cancel,
    LoggedIn,
    Register,
    SendMail,
    ConfirmEmail,
    Account,
    View,
    SendMessage
}
```

and I have created EventLogger class for log event from whole application.

```
  public class EventLogger 
{

    public static IUserEventLogService UserEventLogService
    {
        get
        {
            return Core.ContainerManager.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<IUserEventLogService>();
        }
    }
    public static IUnitOfWorkAsync UnitOfWork
    {
        get
        {
            return Core.ContainerManager.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<IUnitOfWorkAsync>();
        }
    }
    public static async Task Log(DateTimeOffset eventTriggeredOn, Enum_EventType eventType, string eventName, Enum_LogType logType, string logMessage,string eventId = "", string logDescription = "")
    {

        var currentUserId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        string ipAddress = GetLocalIPAddress();
        var userEventLog = new UserEventLog()
        {
            EventId = eventId,
            LogType = logType,
            EventName = eventName,
            EventTriggeredOn = eventTriggeredOn,
            EventType = eventType,
            LogMessage = logMessage,
            LogDescription = logDescription,
            IPAddress = ipAddress,
            UserID = currentUserId,
            ObjectState = Repository.Pattern.Infrastructure.ObjectState.Added,
            SourceType = Enum_SourceType.User
        };
        UserEventLogService.Insert(userEventLog);
       await UnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
    {
        string visitorIPAddress = GetVistorIp(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables);  
        return visitorIPAddress;
    }
    static string GetVistorIp(NameValueCollection headers)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headers["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
            return headers["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headers["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]))
            return headers["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
        return headers["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }
}
```

Please suggest me if this solution is right or require any modification or any good solution for suggestion for my implementation.

Comment: Drop the static class and inherit from an interface and use DI, your code will be testable and injectable to whomever needs it!

Answer (score 7):

[Again](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/185381/13424) enums should not have any prefix. Drop all those `Enum_`! You may like to take a look to [.NET Naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx).

Inside the class `UserEventLog` you do not need to repeat `Log` prefix for its properties. For example just `Message` is enough. Think about a `Window` object: did you ever see properties named `WindowTitle`, `WindowSize`, `WindowCanMaximize` and so on?

Validate values, I might assign `null` to `LogMessage` (or an invalid enum for `EventType`) and it will go straight to the DB engine (which might reject it or not).

Do not *hide* resolved services in a property like `UnitOfWork` and `UserEventLogService`. If you use those objects more than once in the same call then it's a performance hit you do not want to pay (because it has to be resolved for each call and it might event be a new object, it depends on how it's configured in your DI framework). Resolve them once in ctor or better accept them as parameters.

In addition of a single method `Log()` with all those parameters you may want to introduce few extension methods (or overloads):

```
public static async Task LogUserWarning(this EventLogger logger,
                                        DateTimeOffset eventTriggeredOn,
                                        string eventName,
                                        string message)
{
    // ...
}
```

Think twice before using default values for parameters. If you own this code and the calling code then it's not an issue (probably) but if your code is released as a library, to be used by someone else, then you're introducing a strong contract (simply changing default value will not update callers unless they're recompiled, not to mention that they have to check if new values are what they expect). For a real-world example of this issue you may read [Adding option parameter to a library in c# without creating a breaking change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44109496/1207195)
.

Using `String.Empty` instead of `null` for a string entry in a DB may be a waste but it depends on DB engine you're using (for example compare SQL Server and Oracle).

I see no reason for `EventLogger` to do not be `sealed`.

Do not use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` directly. Accessing a static property makes impossible to **test** your code in unit testing outside an HTTP request. The same is true for `GetLocalIPAddress()`. If really you can't avoid it then move it to a derived class, at least you can test all the underlying logic in isolation. Better would be to introduce a service to retrieve those information:

```
interface IHttpRequestInspector
{
    string GetIpAddress();
    string GetAuthenticatedUserName();
}
```

Now you can create a default implementation using the code you already have but you can also have a `MockedHttpRequestInspector` class which can be used in unit testing:

```
sealed class MockedHttpRequestInspector : IHttpRequestInspector
{
    public MockedHttpRequestInspector(string ipAddress, authenticatedUserName)
    {
        _ipAddress = ipAddres;
        _authenticatedUserName = authenticatedUserName;
    }

    public string GetIpAddress() => _ipAddress;
    public string GetAuthenticatedUserName() => _authenticatedUserName;

    private readonly string _ipAddress;
    private readonly string _authenticatedUserName;
}
```

Some properties you declared in `UserEventLog` are not used in code you show (for example `UserEventLog.User`). Drop them?

Comment: for log event i have used every time                                                    
 await EventLogger.Log(DateTimeOffset.Now, Enum_EventType.Update, "Update Listing", Enum_LogType.Information, "Completed",  listing.ID.ToString());

Comment: in my implementation in every call savechanges() in db is there any way to reduce this database call.

Comment: Then you may create a simple most used, overload or extension method for that. To simplify caller to EventLogger.LogInfo(EventType.Update, "Update Listing", "Completed", listing.ID.ToString());

Comment: You may introduce a mem-cache to save batches but I'd add such complexity only if you have a MEASURED requirement. Also ORM and DBE you're using may already have in-place effective optimizations.

Comment: "Do not use System.Web.HttpContext.Current directly" then for get ip address i need to pass parameter in log() method right? and pass this ip value from calling method

Comment: Yes or...not. You can pass it as parameter or inject a service to resolve it. Default implementation may access directly `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` (for both `User` and `Request`) but you open your code to testing. For testing purposes you may mock that interface to provide test values you need and then all this code will be testable in unit testing! Of course you will need some integration tests (at least to test the whole implementation and the concrete classes) but they're small, fast and easy to write.

Comment: can we add DateTimeOffset eventTriggeredOn in Log() method rather than every time pass from calling method is this right way?

Comment: "Right" depends on your use-case but yes, in general, I pick the timestamp directly in the `Log()` method. It's not a problem if you do not have 10,000 requests per second and time spent in processing is negligible (otherwise you may want to have a slightly more accurate timestamp, possibly related to when request has been accepted and not when log effectively will be written).

Comment: Think, for example, 5 requests _received_ within 10 ms from the same client. Something went wrong (and you can easily see it from timestamps). If however 5 requests are _completed_ in 10 ms it may be a server load issue (and user repeated the request because she didn't get any response for, let' say, 10 seconds). A VERY naive log inspector may help you to quickly build some analytic data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72207/discussion-between-ljdhameliya-and-adriano-repetti).

Comment: I would posit that the two `Get` methods are 100% textbook candidates for being get-only properties instead. And given C# 6 or later, it removes the need for the private member variables.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer yes, they might be properties but, at least in the _real_ implementation (not the mock), they may throw exceptions and I'd avoid to have getters which _may_ throw. From a more abstract point of view I see them as _methods_ because they're not trivial properties.

Comment: Yeah, you're completely right about that. Retract my thought line :)

Answer (score 1):

Logger are very important for any project.  In general logger design should be flexible enough to provide custom implementation along with that it should be able to work with existing log providers available in market such as Log4net etc..

I have an application in GitHub where you can use it.

visit https://github.com/tgvishnu/CSharp/tree/master/Vishnu.Logger

1. Log interface should expose simple method and add as extension methods

   ```
   public interface ILog
   {
      bool Log(LogLevel logLevel, Func<string> message, Exception exception = null);
   }
   ```
2. ILogProvider interface return the ILog implementer

   ```
   public interface ILogProvider
   {
       ILog GetLogger(string loggerName);
   }
   ```
3. Create an enum for different Log levels

   ```
   public enum LogLevel
   {
        Trace,
        Debug,
        Info,
        Warn,
        Error,
        Fatal
    }
   ```
4. Add extension methods to ILog inteface for each type of enum

   ```
   public static class LogExtensions
   {
       private static void LogFormat(this ILog logger, LogLevel logLevel, string message, params object[] args)
       {
           var result = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, message, args);
           logger.Log(logLevel, () => message);
        }

        public static bool IsDebugEnabled(this ILog logger)
        {
           if (logger.IsDebugEnabled())
           {
               logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, () => message);
           }
        }

        public static void Debug(this ILog logger, string message)
        {
            if (logger.IsDebugEnabled())
            {
               logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, message);
            }
        }
        public static void Debug(this ILog logger, Func<string> message)
        {
            if (logger.IsDebugEnabled())
            {
               logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, () => message, exception);
            }
        }

        public static void DebugException(this ILog logger, string message, Exception exception)
        {
            if (logger.IsDebugEnabled())
            {
                 logger.LogFormat(LogLevel.Debug, message, args);
             }
        }

        public static void DebugFormat(this ILog logger, string message, params object[] args)
        public static bool IsErrorEnabled(this ILog logger)
        public static void Error(this ILog logger, string message)
        public static void Error(this ILog logger, Func<string> message)
        public static void ErrorException(this ILog logger, string message, Exception exception)
        public static void ErrorFormat(this ILog logger, string message, params object[] args)
        public static bool IsTraceEnabled(this ILog logger)
            .......

        public static string DefaultMessageFormat(this ILog logger, string component, LogLevel level, string message, Exception ex)
       {
           var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
           stringBuilder.Append(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
           stringBuilder.Append(" ");
           stringBuilder.Append(component);
           stringBuilder.Append(" => ");
           stringBuilder.Append(("[" + level.ToString().ToUpper() + "]").PadRight(8));
           stringBuilder.Append(message);
           if (ex != null)
           {
            stringBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine).Append(ex.GetType());
            stringBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine).Append(ex.Message);
           stringBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine).Append(ex.StackTrace);
            }

          return stringBuilder.ToString();
       }
   ```
5. Create a provider class in the project , where you can define list of available for the solution.  Add the log provider available, the log providers should be added in the sequence based on their usage.

   ```
   public static class SampleLogProviders
   {
       private static ILogProvider _currentLogProvider = null;
       public delegate bool IsLoggerAvailable();
       public delegate ILogProvider CreateLogProvider();
       public static readonly List<Tuple<IsLoggerAvailable, CreateLogProvider>> LogProviderCollection = new List<Tuple<IsLoggerAvailable, CreateLogProvider>>()
       {
            new Tuple<IsLoggerAvailable, CreateLogProvider>(DebugLogProvider.IsLoggerAvailable, ()=> new DebugLogProvider()),
            new Tuple<IsLoggerAvailable, CreateLogProvider>(ConsoleLogProvider.IsLoggerAvailable, ()=> new ConsoleLogProvider()),
       };

       public static ILog GetLogger(string name)
       {
           ILogProvider provider = _currentLogProvider ?? ResolveLogProvider();
           ILog result = provider.GetLogger(name) ?? new NoLog();
           return result;
        }

        private static ILogProvider ResolveLogProvider()
        {
             ILogProvider result = null;
             foreach(var provider in LogProviderCollection)
             {
                 if(provider.Item1() == true)
                 {
                      result = provider.Item2();
                      break;
                  }
              }

              return result;
            }
    }
   ```
6. Create Log providers, in the above step we have used DebugProvider and ConsoleProvider, example of Console provider is shown below

   ```
   public class ConsoleLogProvider : ILogProvider
   {
       public ILog GetLogger(string loggerName)
       {
           return new ConsoleLog(loggerName);
       }
       public static bool IsLoggerAvailable()
       {
           return true;
       }
   }
   ```
7. Create LogBase class (this is optional)

   ```
   public abstract class LogBase : ILog
   {
       public virtual bool Log(LogLevel logLevel, Func<string> message, Exception exception = null)
       {
           if (message == null)
           {
               return this.IsLoggerEnabled(logLevel);
           }

           this.WriteMessage(logLevel, message(), exception);
           return true;
       }

       protected string GetDetaultMessage(string component, LogLevel level, string message, Exception ex)
       {
           return this.DefaultMessageFormat(component, level, message, ex);
       }

       protected abstract void WriteMessage(LogLevel level, string message, Exception ex = null);

       protected virtual bool IsLoggerEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
       {
           return true;
       }
   }
   ```
8. Create Console Log class derived from LogBase or implement ILog interface directly.

   ```
   namespace Vishnu.Logger
   {
       public class ConsoleLog : LogBase
       {
           private readonly dynamic _logger;

           private Dictionary<LogLevel, ConsoleColor> _foregroundColors = new Dictionary<LogLevel, ConsoleColor>
                       {
                           { LogLevel.Fatal, ConsoleColor.Red },
                           { LogLevel.Error, ConsoleColor.Yellow },
                           { LogLevel.Warn, ConsoleColor.Magenta },
                           { LogLevel.Info, ConsoleColor.White },
                           { LogLevel.Debug, ConsoleColor.Gray },
                           { LogLevel.Trace, ConsoleColor.DarkGray },
                       };

           public ConsoleLog(dynamic logger)
           {
               _logger = logger;
           }

           protected override void WriteMessage(LogLevel level, string message, Exception ex = null)
           {
               ConsoleColor color = ConsoleColor.White;
               string msg = base.GetDetaultMessage((string)_logger, level, message, ex);
               if (_foregroundColors.TryGetValue(level, out color))
               {
                   var originalColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
                   try
                   {
                       Console.ForegroundColor = color;
                       Console.Out.WriteLine(msg);
                   }
                   finally
                   {
                       Console.ForegroundColor = originalColor;
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   Console.Out.WriteLine(msg);
               }
           }

           protected override bool IsLoggerEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
           {
               return base.IsLoggerEnabled(logLevel);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
9. Create a Logger class in the main application, and enable log for each features that you want to log. Logging for each feature can be set from App.config settings

   ```
   public class Logger
   {
       private static readonly ILog _feature1 = Create(typeof(Feature1));
       private static readonly ILog _feature2 = Create(typeof(Feature2));
       private static readonly ILog _feature3 = Create("Feature3");

       public static ILog Feature1
       {
           get
           {
               return _feature1;
           }
       }

       public static ILog Feature2
       {
           get
           {
               return _feature2;
           }
       }

       public static ILog Feature3
       {
           get
           {
               return _feature3;
           }
       }

       internal static ILog Create(string name)
       {
           return InitializeLogFacade(name);
       }

       internal static ILog Create(Type type)
       {
           return Create(type.FullName);
       }

       private static ILog InitializeLogFacade(string name)
       {
           return LogProviders.GetLogger(name);
       }
   }
   ```
10. Use the logger as below

    ```
    public class Feature1
    {
        public static void GenerateLogs(string message)
        {
            Logger.Feature1.Debug(message);
            Logger.Feature1.Fatal(message);
            Logger.Feature1.Error(message);
            Logger.Feature1.Trace(message);
            Logger.Feature1.Info(message);
            Logger.Feature1.Warning(message);
            Logger.Feature1.DebugException(message, new Exception("Debug exception"));
            Logger.Feature1.FatalException(message, new Exception("Fatal exception"));
            Logger.Feature1.ErrorException(message, new Exception("Error exception"));
            Logger.Feature1.TraceException(message, new Exception("Trace exception"));
            Logger.Feature1.InfoException(message, new Exception("Info exception"));
            Logger.Feature1.WarningException(message, new Exception("Warning exception"));

        }
    }
    ```

Comment: Why so complicated? Why not pass the logger interface directly by DI to whoever needs it? No need for most of your code.

Comment: Design is to provide                                                            
   1.  compatibility  any many providers available in market [SerilogLog, NLog, Log4Net, EntLib, LoupeLog..) as well as to add custom implementation  (EventWriter, Debug, Console, text..).                                        
  2.  Enable logging based on the features/components.                                   If we go with DI, when the requirement changes to use providers in market then we need to change the interface, and to log only specific components / features with this supports all cases